# Could not see help from sysrq command

Tags: sysrq

I'm trying to use some *SysRq* commands on Ubuntu. I use the following to enable `SysRq` commands - `echo "1" > /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq` and then I want to see *help* by writing `h` into `sysrq-trigger` under `/proc`, but I can't see nothing on *stdout*.

You can see a lot more information that could help me and you with *solving* my problem [here](https://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/sysrq.txt)

```
$ echo "1" > /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq
$ echo "h" > /proc/sysrq-trigger
```

**Any suggestions?**

Answer (score 1):

When writing to `/proc/sysrq-trigger`, it actually logs the output of the commands, so I *solved* my problem by simply using `dmesg` which is used to display system logs. There you can find the output of these commands.